# Add Maps-URL to homescreen

Tags: google-maps, home-screen-shortcuts, home-screen, url

How can I add a shortcut with this url to my Homescreen?

`https://maps.app.goo.gl/1234567`

When I open this URL in Chrome, the Maps Application starts and shows the desired page/activity. But because of this instant redirect from Chrome to  Maps it's impossible to use chrome's builtin add-to-homescreen feature for this type of URL.

The final Shortcut should open the Maps-App as Chrome already does. The final shortcut may open my browser just for the redirect into Maps, so a simple URL-Shortcut should be fine.

I tried QuickshortcutMaker but it does not offer to add URLs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution.

I use the App "Url Shortcut" and add a shortcut to open Chrome to navigate and redirect to Maps. For this the URL needs to be changed:

`googlechrome://navigate?url=https://maps.app.goo.gl/1234567`

Comment: I couldn't find "url shortcut". I used [Website Shortcut](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.deltacdev.websiteshortcut&hl=en&gl=US) by [deltac](https://deltacdev.com/) which worked okay for urls.